# Clear cache on nginx server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, nginx, vps

I have a server, when I'm developing a website on my local machine I want to upload it to test it on the production server, however I'm facing a problem from the mobile phone I still get the old version of the server, on the PC I can do a hard refresh however on mobile phone I keep wait until the website refresh is there any solution for this problem? can I clear cache on the server or any other solution?

Comment: nginx doesn't cache things by default, but web browsers do.

Comment: @jordanm so what can i do to the mobile browser to fix that? for example Google Chrome on iPhone 13 pro max?

Comment: You could try setting `Cache-Control: no-cache`. I've don't have experience experimenting with it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @community the question ia clearly, it a bit boxed inside, but if you're reading between the lines you understand that he asks for, bow to disable the nginx cache functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for nginx it would be easy

include this in server or location

```
proxy_cache_bypass                      $http_upgrade;
proxy_no_cache                          1;
proxy_cache_bypass                      1;
proxy_redirect                          off;
proxy_cache                             off;
add_header                      'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
 expires -1;
```

i used /etc/nginx/nocache.conf with the above content and just using include nocache.conf